# How to bind a Command to ItemsControl's template

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I have to create an `ItemsControl` like below and a view model with a clickcommand. How can I bind the command to its template?

```
<ItemsControl Name="connStatusList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#e0e0e0" Margin="0,0,0,0"  MinHeight="325" Width="1700" ItemsSource="{Binding }"  >
   <ItemsControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
         <Border>
            <ItemsPresenter/>
         </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.Template>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel  Name="wp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#ededed"  />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <WrapPanel Width="135" Height="160" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,1,0,0" >
            <WrapPanel Background="{StaticResource connRectangle}"  Width="133" Height="128">
               <Image Source="{Binding WifiImage}" Width="70" Height="53"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,2,0,0"/>
               <Image Source="{Binding ConnectedImage}"  Width="43" Height="63"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,7,0,0" />
            </WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel>
               <Label Content="{Binding ItemNO}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"></Label>
               <Label Content="{Binding Connected}" Name="lblconnected" Visibility="Collapsed"></Label>
            </WrapPanel>
         </WrapPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You might have missed to fill the property `ItemsSource="{Binding }` of your `ItemsControl`. The DataContext of your View should have the Property to Bind to the `ItemsSource` DP and it should be an `ObservableCollection` of your ViewModel that should have Properties like `WifiImage` or `ConnectedImage`

Comment: Does the item view model that contains e.g. `WifiImage` also contain `ClickCommand`?

Answer (score 0):

As you are essentially creating a list of buttons, use a `Button` in your template to bind the command. I assume your command property is called `ClickCommand`. You might need to adapt the style of the button e.g. in mouse-over state to fit your application.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
      <Button.Content>
         <WrapPanel Width="135" Height="160" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,1,0,0" >
            <WrapPanel Background="{StaticResource connRectangle}"  Width="133" Height="128">
               <Image Source="{Binding WifiImage}" Width="70" Height="53"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,2,0,0"/>
               <Image Source="{Binding ConnectedImage}"  Width="43" Height="63"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,7,0,0" />
            </WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel>
               <Label Content="{Binding ItemNO}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"></Label>
               <Label Content="{Binding Connected}" Name="lblconnected" Visibility="Collapsed"></Label>
            </WrapPanel>
         </WrapPanel>
      </Button.Content>
   </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Alternatively, you could use an event trigger from the [`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package. With this approach, the `ClickCommand` is invoked on mouse button up, it does not change any style.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <WrapPanel Width="135" Height="160" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,1,0,0">
      <b:Interaction.Triggers>
         <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
         </b:EventTrigger>
      </b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <WrapPanel Background="{StaticResource connRectangle}"  Width="133" Height="128">
         <Image Source="{Binding WifiImage}" Width="70" Height="53"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,2,0,0"/>
         <Image Source="{Binding ConnectedImage}"  Width="43" Height="63"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,7,0,0" />
      </WrapPanel>
      <WrapPanel>
         <Label Content="{Binding ItemNO}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"></Label>
         <Label Content="{Binding Connected}" Name="lblconnected" Visibility="Collapsed"></Label>
      </WrapPanel>
   </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```